# jQuery validation is not working during button click

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I have a simple page with a form and a button outside the form. I am trying to validate the form on the button click. I have added the rules for validation of the form on the document.onready function. However the form is not getting validated.

HTML

```
<form id="form1" method="post" action="">
  <div>
    <input name="Name" id="name1" data-errorclass="error-name"/>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" id="name_id" value="Save"/>
</form>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#name_id").click(function() {
     alert("called");
     $('.form1').validate({
       rules: {
        'Name' : {
            required: true
         }

       },
       messages: {
        'Name' : {
            required: 'Name is  required'
         }
       },
       errorClass: 'error-name',
       errorPlacement: function(err, element) {
        err.insertBefore(element);
        },        
     });
   });
});
```

**[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B5mVh/)**

Comment: did you try doing $('#form1').submit(function() {....});

Comment: instead of `$("#name_id").click(function() {`

Comment: By fixing the code in your question, the answer no longer makes any sense.  I rolled it back so that readers can understand why the accepted answer works.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As already stated, the original code was targeting a `class`, `.form1`, while the actual form contained `id="form1"`.  Fixing the selector to target the `id` will quickly solve this.

```
$('#form1`).validate({...
```

---

Despite an answer already being posted, I feel the need to also post some important notes regarding some common misconceptions about this plugin.

The `.validate()` method is only used for plugin *initialization*, not a method for *testing* the validity.  So putting `.validate()` inside a `click` handler makes no sense.  `.validate()` only needs to be called one time, so being called repeatedly upon every click is redundant and unnecessary.

**As long as the submit button is inside the `<form>` tags, there is no need for a `click` handler as this is automatically captured by the plugin.   See:  http://jsfiddle.net/B5mVh/6/**

If the button is outside of the `<form>`, you can use the `.valid()` method to *test* the form's validity.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#form1').validate({  // <-- INITIALIZE plugin on your form
        // your rules & options      
    });

    // For button OUTSIDE of form tags
    $("#name_id").click(function() {
        if ($('#form1').valid()) {
            alert("form is valid");
        } else {
            alert("form is invalid");
        }
    });

});
```

DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/B5mVh/4/

However, in your original code, the button is *inside* the form, so as explained before, there's no need for a `click` handler at all.  But if you want to run some code upon the `click` event, use the `submitHandler` (when valid) and `invalidHandler` (when invalid) callback functions.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#form1').validate({  // <-- INITIALIZE plugin on your form
        // your rules & options,
        submitHandler: function(form) {
             alert("form is valid");
             return false;
        },
        invalidHandler: function() {
            alert("form is invalid");
        }
    });

});
```

DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/B5mVh/5/

Of course, you don't have to use these optional callback functions.  The plugin works perfectly fine without them as shown before:

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/B5mVh/6/**

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. May I point out that the documentation http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/ is terrible. It says "validate - validates the selected form". doh! seriously? that is wrong, or meaningless at best. What it should say is "validate - will attach an event handler to the form so that it will get validated at a later time, whenever the submit button is pressed."

Comment: @JohnHenckel, that's not accurate either, because the `.validate()` method does way more, and validation is automatically triggered by other events besides the click of the submit button.  You know the documentation for this ***free*** plugin is available on GitHub.  In other words, instead of complaining, you can submit your contributions, suggestions, additions or corrections to the developer for inclusion.

Comment: @Sparky, I could, but why don't you do it? I bet you'd do a much better job that I would. Just copy-paste a few sentences from your answer to the link I posted. And thanks again.

Comment: @JohnHenckel, thanks... I've made a few minor improvements to the docs in the past.  However, for future reference, [the SO Tag Wiki page is also very informative](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-validate/info).

Answer (score 3):

In jQuery's `validate()` function you call it on a form with the class `.form1`, you should name this correctly to the corresponding ID `#form1`.

This should solve your issue.

Comment: @Sidney Liebrand -No its impossible. If I added like that it would affect other functionalities.

Comment: It's always abit messy working with `ID`'s and `classes` a common mistake that also happened to me plenty of times :)

Comment: Sam: How is it impossible? you are targeting a nonexistent class

Comment: An ID should be unique, if you have multiple same ID's you should change this to a class, otherwise rename your ID to something unique.

Comment: @BarryChapman, he mentioned it will affect multiple items by using that ID, hence I mentioned the above, where he would suggestively change his ID to something unique

Comment: @Sam Do not forget to mark this question answered so that people won't spend more time on this :)